# How could I genericize a range expansion function?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class State {
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public Double A { get; set; }
  public Double B { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two states:

```
State start = new State { Created = DateTime.UtcNow, A = 10.2, B = 20.5 }

State end = new State { Created = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(40), A = 1, B = 80 }
```

I would like to create a List between start and end where the values of A and B evolve in a linear way between their start and end values.

I was able to create a List as follows:

```
IList<DateTime> dates = new Range<DateTime>(start.Created, end.Created,).Expand(DateInterval.Day, 1)
```

Range and Expand are a few helpers I created ...

What is the best way to create the values evolution?

My idea would to do something like:

```
IList<State> states = new Range<State>( // here "tell" how each property would evolve ...)
```

**UPDATE**

Range Class

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T> {

    private T _minimum;
    private T _maximum;

    public T Minimum { get { return _minimum; } set { value = _minimum; } }
    public T Maximum { get { return _maximum; } set { value = _maximum; } }

    public Range(T minimum, T maximum) {
      _minimum = minimum;
      _maximum = maximum;
    } // Range

    public Boolean Contains(T value) {
      return (Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0);
    } // Contains

    public Boolean ContainsRange(Range<T> Range) {
      return this.IsValid() && Range.IsValid() && this.Contains(Range.Minimum) && this.Contains(Range.Maximum);
    } // ContainsRange

    public Boolean IsInsideRange(Range<T> Range) {
      return this.IsValid() && Range.IsValid() && Range.Contains(this.Minimum) && Range.Contains(this.Maximum);
    } // IsInsideRange

    public Boolean IsValid() {
      return Minimum.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0;
    } // IsValid

    public override String ToString() {
      return String.Format("[{0} - {1}]", Minimum, Maximum);
    } // ToString

} // Range
```

A few Range Extensions:

```
public static IEnumerable<Int32> Expand(this Range<Int32> range, Int32 step = 1) {
  Int32 current = range.Minimum;
  while (current <= range.Maximum) {
    yield return current;
    current += step;
  }
} // Expand

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Expand(this Range<DateTime> range, TimeSpan span) {
  DateTime current = range.Minimum;
  while (current <= range.Maximum) {
    yield return current;
    current = current.Add(span);
  }
} // Expand
```

Comment: Did I understand this correctly: you wish to populate a list with `start`, `end` and `n` amount of interpolated states?

Comment: What have you tried?  Seems like calculating the delta based on the difference divided by the number of data points minus 1 would do the trick.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to create a helper classes that accomplish this the same way as I do for DateTime ... So instead of applying it to a DateTime or an Int32 I would apply it to the properties of a class.

Comment: I added extra info to try to better explain what I am trying to do ...

Comment: @Miguel If you want interpolate generics, you have to expose some substractable/additable properties of them through interface or be able to add/substract generics themselves...

Comment: I'm not sure about making a `Range<State>` because `State` would have to implement `IComparable` and how would you compare them.  For example {2015/1/1, 1, 1} and {2015/1/2, 0, 1}.  The deal is you want ranges for each part.

Comment: On the other hand `State` could have a `Add` method to help with the creation of each `State` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var magicNumber = 40;

var start = new State {Created = DateTime.UtcNow, A = 10.2, B = 20.5};
var end = new State {Created = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(magicNumber), A = 1, B = 80};

var stateList = new List<State>(magicNumber);

for (var i = 0; i < magicNumber; ++i)
{
    var newA = start.A + (end.A - start.A) / magicNumber * (i + 1);
    var newB = start.B + (end.B - start.B) / magicNumber * (i + 1);
    stateList.Add(new State { Created = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(i + 1), A = newA, B = newB });
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be divided by n-1 instead of n.  That is the delta would be (end-start)/(n-1).

Comment: if end is 6 and start is 2 and n is 3 you want 2,4,6.  The delta is (6-2)/(3-1) = 2.  And you definitely want to multiple the delta by zero for the first one to get 2, so it would be multiplied by i, not i+1.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong by my idea would be to do what you are doing but by creating a Range<Type> class ... I updated my question .. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you have moved to the stage of genericization where a "mutation step" injectable method that will apply your interpolation becomes logical. Because you don't constrain far enough to know how to interpolate steps, you may need a factory method to create your `Func<T,T>` instances.

For example, if there are two properties whose values shift in your `T`, you would be able to control their rate of change this way.

```
public class Point 
{
    int X {get;set;}
    int Y {get;set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Expand(this Range<T> range, Func<T,T> stepFunction)
                               where T: IComparable<T>
{
     var current = range.Minimum;
     while (range.Contains(current))
     {
         yield return current;
         current = stepFunction(current);
     }
}

// in method
var pointRange = new Range<Point>(
                   new Point{ X=0,Y=0}, new Point{ X=5, Y=20});

foreach (Point p in pointRange.Expand(p => new Point{ p.X + 1, p.Y + 4})
```

Comment: That looks good by unfortunately I can't make Point to implement IComparable since it is an Entity Framework Poco ... So I get the error: The type 'Point' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Range<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Point' to 'Point>'.